# Mysql why 2th column isn't sorted from 1 to 3?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why ordering isn't working right for 2th column. Can some one explain, please.

```
select a,b from d:


+------+------+    
| a    | b    |    
+------+------+    
|    1 |    3 |    
|    1 |    3 |    
|    2 |    1 |    
|    2 |    1 |    
|    3 |    2 |    
|    3 |    2 |    
|    3 |    2 |    
+------+------+



select a,b from d order by a,b;

+------+------+    
| a    | b    |    
+------+------+    
|    1 |    3 |    
|    1 |    3 |    
|    2 |    1 |    
|    2 |    1 |    
|    3 |    2 |    
|    3 |    2 |    
|    3 |    2 |    
+------+------+
```

Comment: `order by` is working as expected: the result set is ordered *first* by `a` and *then* by `b`. So `a=1` records come first, followed by `a=2` records etc. Ordering by `b` occurs within each `a` slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's ordering correctly. In your order by you have asked system to order by First column first so it have ordered then you have asked it to order by second column so it have 
1. It have to keep ordering of first column.
2. Order by second column too

So it does ordering within group means if ..

```
 Table Test 
 A| B
 --------
  1  1
  1  3
  1  2

Select * from test order by A, B 
Output 
A | B 
 1  1 
 1  2
 1  3
```

Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Each record/row in the output has to be consistent. When you use order by, you are printing record/row which is sorted on the basis of specific column value. You can't sort individual column by breaking the consistency of of a row. Otherwise it will create a havoc,  imagine something like `'select bank_account_id, balance from bank_record order by bank_account_id, balance;'`. What do you think would happen if bank_account_id and balance is sorted individually?

Comment: I think most clear example is where first col will contain same values (which could be grouped) and second col just contain unique values. In result order by first,second will group first col and by primary key(if first isn't primary key) will find matches in second col is i understand right?